# How to make a dropdown like this (div with lists inside)?

Tags: html, css, list, drop-down-menu

How to make a dropdown like this?

When he have mouser hover a li from main menu (in this case "Acessórios") to show up a div with some lists inside ...

if possible only with HTML and CSS

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Show us your current code. I guess you tried something...

Comment: what did you do so far??provide your code until now, we are here to help you but not developing your work...

Comment: Try googling "Mega Menu"

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I can't provide a proper answer, but it's a rather vague question and without your existing code there's a limit to how much I can help. But by the looks of things [this example](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/03/05/horizontal-drop-down-menu/) is what you seem to be looking for. You can download the source code for free, and please be sure to ask for any further help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via tabs.

Create

structure for tabs and then create content for all li's on click of particuler anchor just match the id and show that content.

Please see below code -

```
$('.tabs > li > a').click(function () {
        $('.tab-container >.tab-body').hide();
        var $this = $(this);
        var target = $this.attr('href');
        $('.' + target).show();
        $('.tabs > li ').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
        return false;
    });
```

You can get some idea with this JS code